# Closing and reopening of a question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, voting

This question was recently closed:  [Would a teleogenetic standpoint be more useful in discovering certain possibilities about life origins than the theory of abiogenesis?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99488/would-a-teleogenetic-standpoint-be-more-useful-in-discovering-certain-possibilit)

I understood why -- some of the assumptions in the question were prejudicial and disliked by a significant fraction of our posters.

However, I have seen many far weaker and more offensive questions remain open, and this one was both substantive, and generated a lot of highly rated replies (Up to 16 up votes for one reply).  I initiated an open vote, which got up to four votes as of this morning.

However, the open vote list is now down to 1, and my open vote no longer seems to be valid, and cannot be recast until June 15.

I have two questions:

1. Do open votes expire, and do we now have 5 total open votes, but the four prior don't count anymore?
2. Isn't a question about how philosophy of science can deal with substantive questions which are related to a political attack avenue on science while also dealing with the political attack, a relevant topic in philosophy of science, making this a relevant question here, and not appropriately closed?

Thanks for any clarifications provided.  :-)

Comment: 1. [Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/241919).

Comment: The question is making false claim after questionable claim after misrepresentation after false claim after questionable claim. Half of it is at the foundation of the question, making the entire question invalid (this goes far beyond what would just be a frame challenge). The other half is only tangentially related to the question and should probably be altogether removed. I really dislike this mindset that we should welcome deeply flawed questions because there's some value hidden deep in there somewhere. Just let it die and ask a new question without those flaws. That's infinitely better.

Comment: @NotThatGuy -- As I parsed the question, it primarily made two questionable assumptions: 1) that science has a strong and unjustified anti-design/theology bias, and 2) that there is significant evidence for ID alternatives to evolution, that might support an alien creation hypothesis.  Note that incorrect assumptions is NOT one of our close criteria:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions.  CORRECTING incorrect assumptions is actually a big part of our question answering process, and I think it is what i do in a majority of the answers I post.

Comment: @NotThatGuy the guidelines on reopening do not endorse your ""discard the question and resubmit" suggestion, they instead call for editing the question to improve it:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/review-reopen.  And despite the reasons for closing not being on our list, I and several other posters have edited the question -- for one to show how teleology is part of science, and another set to correct the two assumptions you seem to object to in the question, not merely in the answer.  This should be sufficient for yu to vote to reopen, per our guidelines.

Comment: @Dcleve If a question is based on false claims to the point of meaninglessness, it could be argued that it's unclear, too broad and opinion-based. If someone asks whether it's moral for the lizards who run the country to use their invisible unicorns to fight off the aliens who want to share their formula for vampirism with us, I'd say it's fair to close that, because that's just too far detached from reality. You'd probably need to talk to them for weeks to unpack all of that to get to a point where you can do anything useful with it.

Comment: Which part of the guidelines on reopening do you imagine doesn't endorse my suggestion? No part of that says you can't just let a beyond-salvageable question die and ask a new question containing the essence of that question. My suggestion is also supported by basic logic. If a question has a bunch of answers and comments that refers to all its problems, and you need to show some consideration for how the original author wanted to ask their question, and they may still be around... then the question would carry all that baggage around. It's much more logical to just start with a clean slate.

Comment: @Dcleve The bigger problem is perhaps that it tries to paint creationists as trying to "smuggle religious teachings into science textbooks", and from there it phrases the entire discussion as "political" from both sides (vague negative term that doesn't actually mean that much). That's a detrimental misrepresentation of both sides. Firstly, creationists think that creationism is good science, because of their strong religious bias. They're wrong, but they do think so. Building on that, scientists aren't pushing back against religion, they're pushing back against bad (religion-based) science.

Comment: In summary, the question asks "Do the defenses that science has implemented against a political attack undercut the ability to evaluate teleological science questions", but the "attack" is not political, a political attack wouldn't really conceptually make sense, the defenses mentioned do not reflect what's actually been implemented, that can't undercut anything on account of not having been implemented, and it asks about purely-hypothetical teleological science questions that aren't scientific. This is leaning towards lizard overlords fighting vampire aliens with invisible unicorns for me.

Comment: @NotThatGuy -- Political movements will lie to achieve their goals, they operate off what I call "Pravda truth" after the Soviet party organ, where what is "true" changed day to day based on party priorities.   "Bad science" will not endorse explicit falsehoods, so one can distinguish these two. As every creationist web site engages in quote mining, which is explicitly misrepresenting the actual views of evolutionary scientists by selective cherrypicking, Creation Science is a political not science effort.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I considered citing The Prince as a reference that one cannot trust what any organization says publicly once a subject becomes political.  Note that the rationales used to fire the editor were not sufficient to justify the firing over publishing an ID article, which is why they compiled a laundry list of other "offenses" to try to rationalize his firing.  Also, none of the public statements from any of the science organizations endorse banning ID from journals -- they all limit themselves to "teaching".  BUT the unstated agreement is not to publish ID.

Comment: This is a political reaction to a political attack.  I do not criticize that there is a political reaction, I actually consider the political response necessary and appropriate.

Comment: @Dcleve It's easy to just assume that someone is lying when they hold a belief that conflicts with your beliefs. It's hard to suppose they're not lying, and that they believe themselves to be as right as you believe yourself to be. The latter path is more likely to lead somewhere useful. (But yes, I assume at least some people are almost certainly lying, I just don't expect that it's nearly as many as you seem to think it is.)

Comment: @NotThatGuy -- Check out the Politifact ratings:  https://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/  If one is asking a family member about something they did, anything other than the "true" rating is -- dishonest.  IE lies, to various severities.    And only 11% of politicians statements statements actually pass the standard of not being lies to some degree.  Politics drives people to dishonesty.

Comment: Your assertion that the question is incoherent/nonsensical is -- not consistent with either the multiple highly rated answers, or the other attacks on the question and questioner.  While incoherence/nonsense would be justification to close a question, I do not consider that to be credibly apply here.

Comment: @Dcleve What a random website says is kinda irrelevant to my point. Also, the Politifact ratings range from "true" to "false". It isn't make claims about whether the people making the claims believe themselves to be telling the truth or not (there is an additional "pants on fire" rating, but this is more tongue-in-cheek: the description doesn't invoke dishonesty, it just says the claim is ridiculous).

Comment: I fail to see what the scores of answers have to do with my point. It's plausible for people to downvote or close-vote a question and upvote an answer, because you can agree with an answer regardless of whether or not you think the question is useful or on-topic. You're trying to draw a very questionable causal link. Whether my objection is consistent with other objections is largely irrelevant. The validity of my argument is independent of what other people think, much like believing that the Earth is round is either accurate or not, regardless of what other people think.

Comment: Recently I posed a Question which had gotten 4 close votes. So I did the sensible thing and also voted to close. I then extensively edited and flagged for re-opening. When it had 4 re-open votes, I very sensibly cast the final reopen vote and got on with my life. I had never before voted to close or reopen so it was a fun new participatory experience. "*Kindly remember Rule #6!*"